# Find deleted objects from Online SharePoint calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, calendar, online

I am not sure what is wrong with my code to retrieve the list of the events exist in my online sharepoint calendar without the deleted events:

```
 Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

 Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

 $Creds = New-Object 
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username,$Pass)

 $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($URI)

 $Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username,$Pass)

 $Context.Credentials = $Creds
 $List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)
 $Context.Load($Context.Web.Lists)
 $Context.ExecuteQuery()
 $context.Load($List)
 $context.ExecuteQuery()
 $query = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery(1000)

 $items = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection]$List.GetItems($query)

 $context.Load($Items)
 $context.ExecuteQuery()
 Foreach ($Item in $Items){ $Item.FieldValues }
```

all the `$Items` I am getting are including the items that I have already delete from the web (them are not appearing anymore).

These anyone can see what I am doing wrong and how can I fix it to eliminate the deleted events?
Need to be solved only thru PowerShell.

Thanks
Tal

Comment: script looks good. Can you check recycle bin? Thats odd what is going on, but check it.

Comment: How I can check in recycle bin from PowerShell?

Comment: Look simply in UI Site Settings on Root SA and Recycle bin

Comment: This is not my answer as all is need to be done automatically then it is need to be done from PowerShell, any other suggestion? Thanks

Comment: yay, I only want you to check if there is something, because you SHOULD NOT get deleted items from library or list, so the items must be still in library/list but not in the view?

Comment: I have looked in UI the Recycle Bin was fulled, but I have cleared it and still same old deleted event are getting by Powershell query and not shown in UI Calendar.

Comment: Are you looking to the correct view? may you check if you have set any filter in this view or there was set automatically? This is simple SharePoint List - Calendar, right?